# Solr Multicore UpdateXML

Tags: xml, solr

I have two cores on my server and I have made this as a request xml
    *:*
I run
    `java -Durl=http:/localhost:8983/solr/multimedia/update -jar post.jar deleteSites.xml`
I get

```
SimplePostTool version 1.5
```

`Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/multimedia/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file deleteSites.xml
    1 files indexed.
    COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/multimedia/update..`

I run 
    java -jar post.jar deleteSites.xml 
I get
    `SimplePostTool version 1.5`
    `Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type application/xml..`
    `POSTing file deleteSites.xml
    1 files indexed.
    COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..`

I have one core named multimedia and I want to use an XML to update one of the cores. Even without the -Durl, neither of the two cores have any difference in the number of results they contain (they should be deleted)

The delete sites xml is as follows : `<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you can leverage the post.jar file to issue a delete query to Solr. While it uses the same update handler that is coded specifically to post(add) documents to the index. As you can see from the response that you are receiving.

> ... POSTing file deleteSites.xml 1 files indexed ...

In order to issue a delete query I would recommend using the following [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) command:

```
 curl http://localhost:8983/solr/multimedia/update?commit=true -H 
   "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

You can get more details on using [delete commands and other UpdateXMLMessages](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query) on the Solr Wiki.

Comment: I found out that im using the BETA 4.0.0 and you have to add this to your schema
**IMPORTANT : There is a glitch and u must edit the schema.xml and add this line
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
Otherwise, there will have a silenterror. And Yes, I can also use the CURL, thanks for answering

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the bug in 4.0.0 BETA. Do you have a link to this issue?